# Mitigating Cloud Run's limitation regarding Cloud SQL connections per instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I link my Cloud SQL instances to Cloud Run with the `--add-cloudsql-instances` argument.

Some requests are getting 500 Internal Server error in it's responses. Looking at the logs, I was able to know that Cloud Run **"Exceeded maximum of 100 connections per instance..."**. I know that Cloud Run limits to 100 the number of connections that each Cloud Run instance can do to Cloud SQL.

I have already tried to set lower concurrency levels in my Cloud Run service as a way to avoid each instance from exceeding the limit, but the problem never dies. What can I do to mitigate this behaviour and bring my application back to normal stability?

PS. I can't find good and recent answers on this anywhere in the internet, so I decided to ask here.

Details about my last Cloud Run revision: 4 vCPUs, 6GB of RAM, --concurrency of 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a concurrency of 32, and a connection limit of 100, you have a connection problem. You are either not closing connections before returning an HTTP response (leaving unused connections) or you are opening more than one connection per HTTP request and possibly not closing them.

You will need to do a code review for database connection handling.

Opening database connections is an expensive operation. Opening more than one connection per HTTP request consumes time and resources. Use Connection Pooling to resuse connections to increase performance and prevent exhausting open connection limits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you always help me here ;)
 This limit of 100 connections regards the total number of connections made from an instance or is it about the current number of active/open/unclosed connections to the database?

Comment: Also, reducing the concurrency level per instance is not a good workaround? I plan to review my codebase soon, but it is huge. The Connection Pooling workaround has any downside?

Comment: @deniable_encryption - The 100 connection limit is the maximum number of connections that are open (not closed). Even if a connection is not active, it still counts towards the maximum. I wrote an article that covers this topic. The code is Node.js: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-sql-for-mysql-connection-security-high-availability-and-failover/

Comment: @deniable_encryption - If you have a bug that is forgetting to close connections, reducing the concurrency will only prolong how long it takes to reach the maximum.

Comment: Would implementing exponential backoff in my code serve as a workaround? At least to avoid error 500 being returned to the users. I am in doubt, as the algorithm would probably try the exponential backoff from the same Cloud Run instance, always causing the same error, or Cloud Run kills the instance when it exceeds that limit?

Comment: If your code is not closing connections, then waiting will not solve the problem.

Comment: I've checked: The code opens only one connection per request, which isn't closed explicitly, but "PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.". There's something else I can do besides connection pooling? Am I right to think that connection pooling may have downsides?  * Context: This answer left me worried about connection pooling in PHP: stackoverflow.com/a/3332106/11450710

Comment: Is your script ending on Cloud Run? Only when the container is terminated. You must explicitly close connections because the actual Cloud SQL connection is opened by the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy.

Comment: I do not think that **private IP** or **serverless VPC connector** affect the limit. The limit is 100 open connections.

Answer (score -1):

Restrict the load to your application by setting a HTTPS load balancer.